# PHP has a bug comparing after divide

Tags: php, floating-point, integer

I have a problem with PHP comparing after I divide a value float and integer.

Here my code :

```
<?php

    function test_promo($price) {
        $tmpprice = $price*100;
        $divprice = $tmpprice/intval($tmpprice);
        if ( $divprice > 1 ) {
            echo "$price = TRUE\n";
            //TODO do something >1
        }
        else {
            echo "$price = FALSE\n";
            //TODO do something <=1
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    test_promo(2.41);   //output--> 2.41 = FALSE
    test_promo(2.42);   //output--> 2.42 = FALSE
    test_promo(2.43);   //output--> 2.43 = TRUE
    test_promo(2.44);   //output--> 2.44 = FALSE
    test_promo(2.45);   //output--> 2.45 = TRUE
    test_promo(2.46);   //output--> 2.46 = FALSE
    test_promo(2.47);   //output--> 2.47 = TRUE
    test_promo(2.48);   //output--> 2.48 = FALSE
    test_promo(2.49);   //output--> 2.49 = TRUE
    echo "</pre>";

?>
```

As you can see the result must be all FALSE but it's not :S

Is it a bug in PHP or just only my computer (Ubuntu x64) has this bug?

**SOLUTION :**

As the corrected answer below, I need to get only float number as define (the number after `.`) like this `$divprice = number_format( $newprice/intval($newprice), 2 );`

Comment: This is related to floating point manipulation.  I see no reason to suspect all these values must be false.

Comment: No, I need the other float that existing to test. if I put value `test_promo(2.444)` I will lost a number `0.4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Floating points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) can not represent **exactly** the value you posted in decimal. In other words, `2.43` is not really `2.43`, but actually [something close to] `2.4300000000000003`. So when you divide `243.00000000000003` by `243` the result will be greater than `1`.

This is not a bug in PHP, just the way [floating point works](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) (in any language). If you need to work with exact decimal values, you'd better search for a specific library to do that. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4502588/520779) might be a good starting point.

Comment: Got it! I found the bug as you do. Also I found the solution too ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast $divprice to integer because your $divprice is float now and because of this fact:

[PHP.NET](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

> testing floating point values for equality is problematic, due to the
>   way that they are represented internally. However, there are ways to
>   make comparisons of floating point values that work around these
>   limitations.

Solution:

```
$divprice = (int) ($tmpprice/intval($tmpprice));
```

Comment: If I set like this `$divprice = (int) ($tmpprice/intval($tmpprice));` it always return `1`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to how floating point numbers are handled (in any language). You could call this round-off error or whatever but as a general rule it is not recommended to compare floating points for equality. So in this case using `if($divprice==1)` would also give unexpected results.

Comment: I want it's `>1` and `<=1`. also, I try `==` it's still the same bug.