# Rounding error in PHP 5.3.28

Tags: php, rounding

I just ran into a peculiar problem in PHP. What should this result in?

```
floor(100 * (5.8 - floor(5.8)))
```

This should equal `80`, but I keep getting `79`, which is obviously wrong. Any suggestions? Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Welcome to floating point math

Comment: See also: http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

Comment: Also happens in javascript: put Math.floor(100 * (5.8 - Math.floor(5.8))) into your console.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502588/doing-exact-real-number-arithmetic-with-php for possible solutions.

Comment: Everyone has the same problem, floating point math is imprecise.

Comment: Don't take the floor of your result.  Just leave it at `100 * (5.8 - floor(5.8))`.  It might not be practical for your application, but it will return 80.

Comment: 5.8 was just an example in this case, the target was to get exactly two decimal digits from a float